# How to deploy a laravel project from local to server

Tags: php, laravel, git

Im sure this is a very old question, but I'm new to server and cpanel, I went into google and youtube to find a simple tutorial from scrach about how to upload project from local to server.
I have cpanel and already enabled ssh, also I can access to server folders via putty, what I want is:
when I edit on any file on localhost, the to upload the new modification to the server, I dont know how to do this but i have github account, and my laravel project on capnel(shared host) working fine.
I hope you have step by step tutorial so to help me to do this
thank you

Comment: i would recommend using file zilla and manually transfer the files over after you edit them. You can access your ftp credentials from your cpanel account

Comment: but how if I want to use github so may I have a friend will modify in the code and will upload the updates?? I need a way to use github with server, my project allready there in cpanel folder and working fine

Comment: there's multiple ways to do this, i'm not familiar with some of them, but this is how I would do it: i would let him update the github repo, then you pull his changes to your machine and upload it yourself through filezilla. This way, your stay up to date with his changes as well. I wouldn't feel comfortable with multiple people having upload access to the live project. Again, this is a personal preference, nothing wrong with trying to figure out how to do it another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, your server has ssh enabled. So u have a great advantage here. I'm gonna guide u through you simply here.

Here is the first step:

Go to your laravel project folder and then run command via git bash ( make sure ur pc has git bash installed if not click [here](https://git-scm.com/downloads)) :

```
git init
```

This will create a git repo in your project directory. 
then run:

```
git add .  
git commit -am"first commit"
```

After that, go to your browser and login your github account, create a new repository. Keep it private/public as u like. Now u can see github give u several commands about how to commit and push your code into repo. you just run this

```
git remote add origin .... ( your repo link given by github ) 

git push -u origin master
```

All your code is now on github. Now the server part !

1. Login to ur server via ssh
2. change your directory to public_html
3. take the clone link from your github repo you just created ( green button saying Clone or Download make sure you copy clone with https link)
4. now run command inside your public_html

```
git clone <<your_repo_link>>
```

5. Done. Now create a database via ssh using command :

```
 mysql -u <<user_name>> -p
```

it will ask you for the password. give the password and create a database. ( you can create db from cpanel as well, thats easier than cli ) edit your .env file. I'm assuming I don't need further explanation as you are already working with laravel.

Finally create a softlink using ln -sr public_html public_html/public so that when you hit your domain it can load the index.php from your public folder as laravel app runs from public/index.php.

Hope it helps.

Comment: all fine but last one about softlink didnt get it, where I have to create this and how?? also please note that I uploaded all files to the main root not to public_html, but public_html have the index.php and .htaccess also all the public files

Comment: until now I dont know how to do update from local to server, what I can do now is just modify on local then using push I can see the modification in github but not in server

Comment: I hope I get answer from you soon!

Comment: Sorry for late reply bro, 

Answering your first question: 

When you using a server with cpanel, generally it uses public_html folder for main domain root. however you can change it. 

or you may add a subdomain and define the root for that domain in cpanel's subdomain option. 

But when you are deploying a single laravel application to your domain, think about it, laravel application uses its public/ folder as document root and cpanel's uses public_html or www folder as document root. So when you hit your domain cpanel's html come in action.

Comment: by using ln -sr command you can link your laravel's public/ folder in cpanel's public_html so than when you hit your domain your cpanel will redirect into laravel's public/ folder and from there it will get index.php

Comment: Answering your second question.

after pushing in your local branch on git. you have to use git pull command in live server fetch the update from git hub. 

I would suggest you to learn version controlling. there are tons of tutorials in youtube will help u out about version controlling. 

you can do a lot of stuff with git., pushing , pulling is not only purpose of using git. anyway. hope it will clear your confusion

Comment: Thank you brother but Im very new to server and github, until now I didnt get where I have to go to write the code to tell the git that the public content in the public_html, also I used putty to pull the update from github but Im sure there is an automatic way to update to server from local but dont know how?

Comment: No prb brother, there are lots of tutorial out there. you can utilize those. you just need to clear the concept of version controlling. here is a useful tutorial, I learned from here 4 years ago

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cEGIFZDyszA&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGAKWClAD_iKpNC0bGHxGhcx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202464/discussion-between-ash-malek-and-fahim152).